# How to always round a number UP to the nearest penny in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of numbers, for example `797.3333333333334`, `852.22222111`, `933.111023`, which I want to ALWAYS round up to the nearest penny, such that the numbers I already mentioned would be `797.34`, `852.23`, `933.12`, respectively.

I said the nearest penny, but you might also call it the nearest tenth.

There is a ceiling function, but that only rounds to the nearest integer, as does `Math.round()`

Comment: `ceil` doesn't round to nearest integer, it gets the first integer larger or equal to your number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Math.ceil(x) function returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a number "x".](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```
var rounded = Math.ceil(yourNumber * 100)/100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this: `Math.ceil(number * 100) / 100`.

Answer (score 0):

Properly rounding to the nearest penny:

```
var yourNumber = 5.495;
yourNumber = Math.round(yourNumber * 100)/100;
alert(yourNumber);
```

**Always** round up to the nearest penny:

```
function precision(a) { 
  if (!isFinite(a)) return 0;
  var e = 1, p = 0;
  while (Math.round(a * e) / e !== a) { 
    e *= 10; p++; 
  }
  return p;
}
if (precision(yourNumber) >= 3) {
  yourNumber = (Math.trunc(yourNumber * 100)/100) * 1 + 0.01;
}
```

Comment: maudulus, Do you have any resources on how to manage garbage collection in html5 canvas?